# Can anyone please help me identify my house plant?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I know this may be an impossible task, but I am one to hope ! My mum had a house plant which had small, green, oval shaped leaves which naturally grew towards the ground (hanging plant). Once every year the plant would flower for several weeks to several months and would have little white flowers bloom. Inside the white flowers were pink baby flowers (they were tiny) and they looked like they were made of glass ! The plant did not need much maintenance and was easy to keep happy, I live in the UK.

Unfortunately my mum died last year but had given the plants to my nan for safe keeping whilst we moved house and she refused to give them back to us. I was hoping to buy one as a memento to my mum, but I cannot find it anywhere and I have no clue as to its name and I sadly do not have any photos. Can anyone help me at all please ?

Thank you,
Molly x

Comment: When you say the leaves were small, what size are you thinking of? Could you please edit your post and add an estimate in cm/inch of the leaves, flowers and the whole plant? And where the leaves rather dark or light green?

Comment: Was the white flower star shaped?

Comment: a drawing would be better. your nan can just give you an offshoot or a cutting or a photo.